# Mongoose find() callback not actually being called

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, async-await

I'm new to Mongoose and also using async/await. Right now I have a Mongoose schema, with a static method, like so:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    pass: String
});


userSchema.statics.checkExist = async function(username){
    return await this.findOne({username: username}, function(err, res){
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
        if(res){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

The static method `checkExist()` is supposed to take in a username, and check if a document already exists with the same username. If it does, it should return true, otherwise false. I use it in my NodeJS/Express server like so:

```
router.post('/auth/login', async (req, res) =>{
    let username = req.body.username;

    let existBool = await UserModel.checkExist(username);

    console.log(existBool);
    res.send({'hash': existBool});
});
```

I expect `existBool` to be the true/false boolean. Instead, `checkExist()` doesn't seem to call the callback function at all. Instead it returns the result of `findOne()`, which is an object that has the matching username field. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing callbacks with `async/await` which uses promises. You're also misunderstanding how the callbacks work; The result of the `await` isn't the return value of the callback, it's the return value of `findOne()`.

`await` is used hold until an async function returns a promise, it then "unwraps" that promise into a variable. If the `findOne()` method supports promises, you should not be using the callbacks at all.

```
let result = await this.findOne({username: username})
```

The reason `async/await` is so powerful is because it removes the need for `.then()` promise syntax and lets you write sequential code again, but have it handle async behaviour. It lets you use loops and, most importantly, lets you use `try/catch` statements to handle errors again.

```
try {
  let result = await this.findOne({username: username})
} catch(ex) {
  // handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
        timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: true },
        collection: 'users'
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The Router end point is below

```
// API endpoint to insert new user.
router.post('/insertUser', function (req, res, next) {
    let request = req.body;
    let userSchema = new UserModel({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        username: request.username,
        password: request.password
    }); `enter code here`

    if (!userSchema.username) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: 'Username can\'t be empty' });
    } else if (!userSchema.password) {
        res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: 'Password can\'t be empty' });
    } else {
        // If username is not unique in schema do check this...
        UserModel.findOne({ username: userSchema.username }).exec()
            .then(result => {
                if (result == null) {
                    //Here the User is added
                    userSchema.save().then(result => {
                        res.status(200).json({ success: true, msg: 'User Added' });
                    }).catch(exception => {
                        console.log(exception);
                        res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: 'Something went wrong' });
                    });
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: 'Username already taken' });
                }
            }).catch(exception => {
                console.log(exception);
                res.status(200).json({ success: false, msg: 'Something went wrong' });
            });
    }

});
```